# Trying to concatenate tags to make one file name

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to concatenate two data elements to make a filename for inserting an image. But I can't get the XML to insert the data nodes in the template. I've tried multiple path statements but none of them seem to be working. I'm sure it's something very simple but I can't see it.

I'm trying to return the following name: Surname_FirstName.jpg

I also want to replace any spaces in the names with underscores. I believe I have to add a translate or normalize space command to it. But first I'm trying to just get the Surname and FirstName to appear.

Thanks

Here's the XML sample:

```
 <Data>
 <Consultant>
 <Surname>Hulshoff Pol</Surname>
 <FirstName>Annekee</FirstName>
 <MiddleName></MiddleName>
 <Consultant_photo>HAA.jpg</Consultant_photo>
 </Consultant>
 <Consultant>
 <Surname>Prieto</Surname>
 <FirstName>Al</FirstName>
 <Consultant_photo>JA.jpg</Consultant_photo>
 </Consultant>
 </Data>
```

Here's the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

 <data>
 <xsl:for-each select="Data/Consultant">
 <xsl:sort select="Surname" order="ascending" />
 <consultant>
 <Surname><xsl:value-of select="Surname"/></Surname> 
 <FirstName><xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/></FirstName>
 <xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="Consultant_photo" /><xsl:text>
 </xsl:text>
 </consultant>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </data>

 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Consultant_photo">
   <consultantphoto><xsl:value-of select = "concat(Surname, '_', Firstname)"/>  <xsl:text>.jpg</xsl:text></consultantphoto>
 </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I've also used <xsl:template match="Consultant_photo">
   <consultantphoto><xsl:value-of select = "concat(Surname, '_', Firstname)"/>  <xsl:text>.jpg</xsl:text></consultantphoto>
 </xsl:template>

Comment: The last template won't match anything in your source document. The match use a XPath expression on the source data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to solve your concatenation problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Consultant">
                <xsl:sort select="Surname" order="ascending" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Consultant">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            <consultantphoto>
                <xsl:value-of select="Surname"/>
                <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/>
                <xsl:text>.jpg</xsl:text>
            </consultantphoto>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will add the `<consultantphoto>` element inside `Consultant`. You can also achieve the same result using `concat`:

```
<xsl:copy>
     <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
     <consultantphoto>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(Surname, '_', FirstName,'.jpg')"/>
     </consultantphoto>
</xsl:copy>
```

As for the spaces that were originally in the first names and last names, if you wish to replace them with some separator and are using XPath 2.0, you can use the `fn:replace('Spaced Name', ' ', '-')`, for example, to use a `-` as separator. In XSLT 1.0 you can achieve this, but you will have to use a combination of `concat`, `substring-before` and `substring-after` functions.

Comment: Why do you use `concat('a', concat('b', ... 'c')`? You can simply use `concat('a', 'b', ..., 'c')` instead

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @AJPerez. I lazily used some old code examples I had and replaced the values without checking. I just fixed it.

Comment: You can probably use a `translate` to replace the spaces too. I don't see a reason to over complicate it with using `substring`.

Comment: Do these options SORT the data too? I don't see how it sorts. I also didn't add all the XML data elements to the sample above, but some of the data comes in out of order, so using "*" will only bring the data back in the way it appears in the XML source, right? Do I need to add templates matches at the top to create my desired tag order?

Comment: I edited the answer and added a template for `<Data>` which will sort the `Consultant`s.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are making this more complicated than it needs to be. Try it this way?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method='xml' version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' indent='yes'/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<Data>
    <xsl:for-each select="Data/Consultant">
    <xsl:sort select="Surname" order="ascending" />
        <Consultant>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Surname"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="FirstName"/>
            <Consultant_photo>
                <xsl:value-of select="translate(concat(Surname, '_', FirstName, '.jpg'), ' ', '_')" />
            </Consultant_photo>
         </Consultant>
     </xsl:for-each>
</Data>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is assuming you want to remove the `MiddleName` element and discard the existing content of `Consultant_photo`.

Note also that XML is case-sensitive: `data` is not the same as `Data`, and `Firstname` is not the same as `FirstName`, for example.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this too. But the first answer worked for me. The case was not important and I'm actually using the data in a completely different order, but I didn't want to complicate the question. The only thing I was having problems with was the concatenation.

Comment: Uhm.. the case **is** important when your template says `concat(Surname, '_', Firstname)` and there is no `Firstname` element in your XML.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was referring to changing the case of "consultant". Element names MUST be correct.